# Web Service Security Username Token

Tags: c#, web-services

Is there any good tutorial on how to implement the Web Service security username token in a C# web service header?

Can some body point me to one.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources are explicitly off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article that, I believe, can be of help to you : http://www.primaryobjects.com/2015/05/08/token-based-authentication-for-web-service-apis-in-c-mvc-net/

If you prefer video tutorial, here’s the good one :  https://youtu.be/7E6wNd_9FJ0

I would recommend you to go through article, read it carefully and try to implement it side by side.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: You should also put the answer in your answer as well as give links.